# There is no way to show the "upload panel", without the "file panel" be visible, in ITHit AJAX File Browser?

Tags: javascript, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

Basically: in the initials settings can configure the panel visibility

```
var settings = {
BasePath: '/',                      // path to ajax file browser files 
Id: 'AjaxFileBrowserContainer',     // ID of the parent control 
Url: 'http://webdavserver.com',     // the root folder to be displayed
Style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%',
MsOfficeTemplatesPath: 'http://webdavserver.com/MSOfficeTemplates/',
SelectedFolder: '/Pictures',        // folder to be selected
Panels: {
    Folders: { Show: false },
    FilesView: { Show: false },
    Toolbar: { Show: false },
    AddressBar: { Show: false },
    UploadPanel: { Show: true },
    UploadProgressPanel: { Show: true }
}
```

};

or later, also can show or hide the panel

```
instanceName.SetShowUploadPanel(true);
```

But none of these statements make the Upload Panel visible, so there any way to show the upload panel without the File panel?.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently there is no way to show Upload Panel only. It is a part of a Files View panel and it is visible only if Files View panel is visible. The only solution would be to modify the source codes (the payed version is provided with source codes).